# Is it possible to connect a virtual machine (VirtualBox) to the internet using the host machine as gateway?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have installed a `VirtualBox` machine on my `Windows 10`. I want to connect to the internet through a ethernet connection.

The problem is that I don't know the password for this network, but my host machine is already connected to it.

So, I want to connect to the internet using the `Windows 10` host machine as gateway. I mean, I want to send / receive packets from / to my virtual machine as if they were being sent from my `Windows 10 host`. So, the host machine would be behaving as a router (so to speak) in terms of redirecting packages.

**Is that possible? If so, how can I configure VirtualBox for achieving it?**

Remarks: the guest machine is a `Lubuntu`. I have already tested if I can ping both my host machine and the ethernet netowrk's default gateway and I can reach both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Choose NAT in the VM's NIC settings and it will do what you ask automatically.

Comment: I have already chosen NAT and it does not work.

Comment: 1. Take a screen shot of the VM NIC settings. 2. go into Run - ncpa.cpl and edit the IPv4 settings of the virtual box interface. What IP/netmask is configured? 3. What IP/netmask/next hop router do you get in Linux by the dhcp client?